# Getting an error for using break command in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to use a break in my code for a choice to quit the program, but when I run it, I get "break outside Loop". Is there a way to fix it? I've tried the return command or other commands from other questions similar to this one, but I had no luck with them. Here's the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
v1 = []
v2 = []

while True:

print('Welcome to vector arithmetic! Below is a list of available operations.')

print('1. Enter values for your vectors')
print('2. Print vectors')
print('3. Vector dimensionality')
print('4. Add vectors')
print('5. Compute dot product of vectors')
print('6. Compute magnitude of vectors')
print('7. Quit')

choice = int(input('Enter the number corresponding to your choice: '))

if choice == 7:
    break
elif choice == 1:
    pass
elif choice == 2:
    pass
elif choice == 3:
    pass
elif choice == 4:
    pass
elif choice == 5:
    pass
elif choice == 6:
    pass
else:
    print('Invalid choice, try again')
```

Comment: If that's your real code, there's nothing to "break" out of.  Indentation matters.

Comment: Please make sure that the code you post here reflects *exactly* what you *actually* have. You need an *additional* four spaces in front of *each* line of code, compared to your original source file; you can do this by copying and pasting, then with the *whole block selected*, press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the indentation and white space matters. As the comment above mentions, I just moved that whole block below your while statement into the correct indentation and works as you expect.

```
v1 = []
v2 = []

while True:
    print('Welcome to vector arithmetic! Below is a list of available operations.')
    print('1. Enter values for your vectors')
    print('2. Print vectors')
    print('3. Vector dimensionality')
    print('4. Add vectors')
    print('5. Compute dot product of vectors')
    print('6. Compute magnitude of vectors')
    print('7. Quit')

    choice = int(input('Enter the number corresponding to your choice: '))

    if choice == 7:
        break
    elif choice == 1:
        pass
    elif choice == 2:
        pass
    elif choice == 3:
        pass
    elif choice == 4:
        pass
    elif choice == 5:
        pass
    elif choice == 6:
        pass
    else:
        print('Invalid choice, try again')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not properly indented:

```
v1 = []
v2 = []

while True:

    print('Welcome to vector arithmetic! Below is a list of available operations.')

    print('1. Enter values for your vectors')
    print('2. Print vectors')
    print('3. Vector dimensionality')
    print('4. Add vectors')
    print('5. Compute dot product of vectors')
    print('6. Compute magnitude of vectors')
    print('7. Quit')

    choice = int(input('Enter the number corresponding to your choice: '))

    if choice == 7:
        break
    elif choice == 1:
        pass
    elif choice == 2:
        pass
    elif choice == 3:
        pass
    elif choice == 4:
        pass
    elif choice == 5:
        pass
    elif choice == 6:
        pass
    else:
        print('Invalid choice, try again')
```

As you can see, indentation in python is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are having an **indentation error**, in that case you need to make sure that while you enter anything in a **loop**, **function**, or **class** that it is properly indented.

```
v1 = []
v2 = []

while True:

    print('Welcome to vector arithmetic! Below is a list of available operations.')

    print('1. Enter values for your vectors')
    print('2. Print vectors')
    print('3. Vector dimensionality')
    print('4. Add vectors')
    print('5. Compute dot product of vectors')
    print('6. Compute magnitude of vectors')
    print('7. Quit')

    choice = int(input('Enter the number corresponding to your choice: '))

    if choice == 7:
        break
    elif choice == 1:
        pass
    elif choice == 2:
        pass
    elif choice == 3:
        pass
    elif choice == 4:
        pass
    elif choice == 5:
        pass
    elif choice == 6:
        pass
    else:
        print('Invalid choice, try again')
```

Also, I do not recommend that you use **break** in loops as they can be problematic if they are not implemented properly. Instead, try using **quit**